# Groovy: check at run time if object is a String

Tags: groovy

I'm about to overload the leftShift operator and wanted to know how to check if the given parameter "other" is a String?

```
def leftShift(other){
    if(other.getClass() instanceof String){
        println other.toString() + " is a string!"          
}
```

But this doesn't work.. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 14):

You can use the test that you would normally use in Java.

```
def leftShift(other) {
    if(other instanceof String) {
        println "$other is a string!"
    }
}
```

When you call `other.getClass()` the result class is *java.lang.Class* instance which you could compare against *String.class*. Note *other* can be *null* in which the test "other instanceof String" evaluates to false.

UPDATE:

Here's a simple case that creates a Groovy [GString](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GString.html) instance which is not a string instance:

```
def x = "It is currently ${ new Date() }"
println x.getClass().getName()
println x instanceof String
println x instanceof CharSequence
```

Outputs:

```
It is currently Thu Aug 21 15:42:55 EDT 2014
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl
false
true
```

GStringImpl extends GString which has methods that make it behave as a String object and implements CharSequence interface as does the String class. Check if *other* object is CharSequence which is true if object is a String or GString instance.

```
def leftShift(other) {
    if(other instanceof CharSequence) {
        println "$other is a string!"
    }
}
```

Comment: To handle both `String` and `GString` with the leftshift operator, it might be sensible to test for `CharSequence`: `if (other instanceof CharSequence) { ...`

Comment: Thanks. CharSequence test simplifies this.

Answer (score 6):

It is

```
if (other.getClass() == String)
```

Comment: nothing, doesn't go into the if statement at all. I do not really define a new instance of a String, i only have it like: "teststring". Maybe the problem is here..

Comment: Yes the problem. You need to def str ="aaa"

Comment: nevertheless, is it possible to check the type of the "teststring" anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Code as written won't compile - you're missing a brace.  With that present, `instanceof` works as in Java, as others have mentioned.  However, in Groovy, I'd be careful with checking `instanceof` against `String`, as sometimes what appear to be `Strings` are, in fact, `GStrings` (see [docs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString), section "GStrings aren't Strings").  Quick example:

```
assert "the quick brown $somevar jumped over the lazy dog" instanceof String == false
```